# No puedo conectarme a MySQL desde C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos MySQL en C #, y mi código ha estado funcionando perfectamente desde que comencé, pero a veces sé que me está dando este error como, cada 2 días, a veces conecta a veces no, tengo 2 DB en diferentes servidores y cuando trato de conectarme al segundo servidor funciona siempre, ¿qué pasa?

este es el error

> Se produjo una excepción del tipo 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' en MySql.Data.dll pero no se manejó en el código de usuario
>
> Información adicional: no se puede conectar a ninguno de los hosts MySQL especificados.

Este es mi codigo

```
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    conn_string.Server = Conexion.Server;
    conn_string.Port = Conexion.PORT;
    conn_string.UserID = Conexion.UID;
    conn_string.Password = Conexion.PASSWORD;
    conn_string.Database = Conexion.Database;
    MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());
    SqlCon.Open();
    if (SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel_Con.Text = "Conectado";
        toolStripStatusLabel_Con.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        SqlCon.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel_Con.Text = "Desconectado";
        toolStripStatusLabel_Con.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        SqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Lo unico que se puede decir es que puede que haya información errónea de la conexión, o el usuario no tenga permisos para entrar en la BD. El código parece estar bien así que yo me iria a mirar si el equipo tiene conexión con el servidor (en caso de que sea externo), si el usuario tiene permisos, revisar si las variables contienen la información correcta para conectarte, etc..

Comment: Comprueba que la BBDD permita acceder a equipos externos y las credenciales. Para comprobarlo de manera sencilla puedes usar HeidiSQL

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que la [cadena de conexión](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) sea correcta antes de crear el objeto. 
Con la cadena de conexion prueba en una [aplicación externa](https://www.heidisql.com/) si tienes el mismo problema.

Si con el mismo código puedes acceder a un servidor y a otro no, también puede ser problema de conectividad de red.